# Python - making multiple variables have a new outcome

Tags: python

Please forgive me as I am learning, but I need a bit of help completing an activity.  I have to create a BINGO game with a set card, when the user enters the numbers it will tell them if they got a letter of not.  What I am struggling with is how once the user has all of the letters, how to have them 'win'?

Here's what I have so far:

```
print ("WELCOME to BINGO\n")
print ("Pick numbers between 1-80")
print ("Collect BINGO to win\n")

#BINGOboard
B = {"7","14"}
I = {"26","22"}
N = {"40","34"}
G = {"58","55"}
O = {"73","68"}
x = {"B"+"I"+"N"+"G"+"O"}

#collecting data
number = True
x = False

while number:
    answer = input("Please enter in your guess\n")
    if answer in B :
        print("You have a B!")
    elif answer in I :
        print("You have a I!")
    elif answer in N :
        print("You have a N!")
    elif answer in G :
        print("You have a G!")
    elif answer in O :
         print("You have a O!")
    elif answer in x :
         print("Congrats")
    else:
        print("Sorry that number is not on the board, please try again!\n")
```

Comment: `x` doesn't make any sense in your code at the moment. You should print it at various stages in your program. First you make it `{"BINGO"}` which doesn't really serve any purpose. Then immediately you change it to `False`. Again it's hard to see why. Finally you check `if answer in x` but that doesn't make sense if `x` is either of the things you define it to be.

Comment: Very simply, you need to make some data structure to keep track of which letters you've covered.  Think about how you would do this with pen and paper; then, how can you represent that with Python data types.  After each successful letter identified, update that structure, and check whether you have all five columns yet.  Does that get you moving?

Comment: Hint: rather than five separate variables, use a single collective variable with five elements.

Comment: I think I need to do some more reading!  its annoying being so close yet so far!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I tied to stay true to your original game model, but I spoofed it up a bit. Not just to show you more coding but also to think about somethings going into your code. Like if the user enters a negative or letter. Also what if the user re-enters a number they already have. These are things you want to think about when approaching your code, or you can get far in and have to redesign your entire code to handle issues you overlooked!

Cheers hope this helps!

```
print("WELCOME to BINGO\n")
print("Pick numbers between 1-80\n")
print("Collect BINGO to win")

B = [7, 14]
I = [26, 22]
N = [40, 34]
G = [58, 55]
O = [73, 68]

user = []
win = [B, I, N, G, O]

while sorted(user) != sorted(win):
    guess = -1
    while guess < 0:
        try:
            guess = int(input("\nPlease enter a guess: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    if guess in B:
        if B in user:
            print(f"You already have B!{B}")
        else:
            print("You have a B!")
            user.append(B)
    elif guess in I:
        if I in user:
            print(f"You already have I!{I}")
        else:
            print("You have a I!")
            user.append(I)
    elif guess in N:
        if N in user:
            print(f"You already have N!{N}")
        else:
            print("You have a N!")
            user.append(N)
    elif guess in G:
        if G in user:
            print(f"You already have G!{G}")
        else:
            print("You have a G!")
            user.append(G)
    elif guess in O:
        if O in user:
            print(f"You already have O!{O}")
        else:
            print("You have a O!")
            user.append(O)
    else:
        print("Sorry that number is not on the board, try again!")

print("\nCongratulations you won!")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 bingo.py 
> WELCOME to BINGO
>
> Pick numbers between 1-80
>
> Collect BINGO to win
>
> Please enter a guess: 1
> Sorry that number is not on the board, try again!
>
> Please enter a guess: 7
> You have a B!
>
> Please enter a guess: 14
> You already have B![7, 14]
>
> Please enter a guess: 73
> You have a O!
>
> Please enter a guess: 40
> You have a N!
>
> Please enter a guess: 58
> You have a G!
>
> Please enter a guess: 22
> You have a I!
>
> Congratulations you won!
> ```